# How to save downloaded updates only to be used on a computer without internet

Tags: updates, offline

I searched askubuntu and got many solution, many of which are very complicated and eats huge bandwidth like say building an off-line deb archive. Is there any manual way to save the installed updated and packages only, so that i can use them later to install if anything goes wrong and i have to make a fresh install.

Thanks in advance.

***Aude Sapere***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To download the programs only** without installing them, you can use the `-d` option in `apt-get` like, for example, `sudo apt-get -d install firefox`. This will only download the packages and not install it.

The downloaded packages will be saved in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. You can copy them from there to some other location, and then if you ever need to install the programs, then you can copy them back.

**If you have an offline computer** separately that you want to install packages to, then you could try `apt-offline`. On the offline computer it generates a list of files that need to be downloaded to install a program, and you can then download those files (either manually or using `apt-offline` again) from a different computer and copy them back to install.

There is also a GUI for it called `apt-offline-gui`, which makes the process much more user-friendly.

[image: The apt-offline GUI]

Comment: OK Thanks, so if I do an "apt-get -d install firefox" and then can i install it later with "apt-get install firefox" without internet. Can i similarly use "apt-get -d upgrade" and and later without internet "apt-get upgrade" ?

Comment: @drofart Yes. The `-d` option makes apt perform only the downloading part of whatever command you give it.

Comment: Thanks Hippo, then i guess synaptic will be the best option for newbies like me, it has a option of "only download package files"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Cube](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583)** for that. It is a portable package manager and downloads packages in any computer with internet connection and installs it back for later use, offline. All of the downloaded packages will be located at **cube/projects/[your-project]/data/packages** directory.

[image]

[image]

Or you can also share/give your installed apps / packages to other Linux compatible computer using its **[App Share](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1604)**